# Importing entire module without renaming

Tags: typescript, namespaces

If I import an entire module without renaming the import, are all of the imported declarations available in the importing module's namespace?

Eg:

```
import * 'some_module'
```

Assuming `some_module` has a declaration named `Foo`, would `Foo` be available as such after the import?

Eg:

```
import * 'some_module';

var coolStuff = Foo.coolStuff();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are all of the imported declarations available in the importing module's namespace

No.

> would Foo be available as such after the import?

No. Also there is no *ES6 module* syntax for this.

## Why

*Globals* are hard to analyze and code review. Named imports are easier to review in isolation. Many of the same reasons why [modules are better than globals in the first place](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html). Hope that helps